# Keeping global state in Flask Application

Tags: python, flask

This seems like a pretty obvious question, but a lot of the document around this is very confusing, and warn me *not* to keep a global state instead of telling me how to.

For example, if I need to have a database connection pool (I'm not using SQLAlchemy), or a pool of object instances (both of which need to be *global* pools, centrally managed), how do I do that?

If I use `flask.g`, that's not shared between threads, and if I use a python global, that's not shared between multiple processes of the same application (which, as I understand, can be spawned in the case of large production flask servers). Do I use `flask.current_app`? Do I make the pool a separate process itself? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings about "not keeping a per-process global state" in a web backend app (you'll have the very same issue with Django or any wsgi app) only applies to state that you expect to be shared between requests AND processes.

If it's ok for you to have per-process state (for example db connection is typically a per-process state) then it's not an issue. wrt/ connections pooling, you could (or not) decide that having distinct pools per server process is ok.

For anything else - any state that needs to be shared amongst processes -, this is usually handled by some using some external database or cache process, so if you want to have one single connection pool for all your Flask processes you will have to use a distinct server process for maintaining the pool indeed.

Also note that:

> multiple processes of the same application (which, as I understand, can be spawned **in the case of large production flask servers**)

Actually this has nothing to do with being "large". With a traditional "blocking" server, you can only handle concurrent requests by using either multithreading or multiprocessing. The unix philosophy traditionnally favors multiprocessing ("prefork" model) for various reasons, and [Python's multithreading is bordering on useless](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) anyway (at least in this context) so you don't have much choice if you hope to serve one more one single request at a time.

To make a long story short, consider that just any production setup for a wsgi app *will* run multiple processes in the background, period.